# Where are the best places to take business calls outside of BA lounges in London Heathrow Terminal 5?

Tags: london, lhr, lounges

I'll be flying via London Heathrow Terminal 5 soon. While at the airport I have some business calls planned so will be looking for a place that is quiet enough for a call and has good WiFi (at a minimum good enough for a voice call, ideally good enough for a video call).

Unfortunately, I don't have access to BA's lounges for this trip so my first thought is accessing the two independent lounges, via membership of a lounge access program: Club Aspire and Plaza Premium. However, from their reviews and photos, they don't look like they'll be a good place to make calls. Plaza Premium has [booth-like seats](https://www.plazapremiumlounge.com/PlazaPremiumLounge/media/PPLMedia/Lounges/LHR/LHR_Dep_T5/LHR_Dep_T5_1600x800_Web4.jpg) that afford some privacy however a lot of [reviews](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Plaza+Premium+Lounge+(Departures,+Terminal+5)+London+Heathrow+Airport+(LHR)/@51.4731325,-0.4871593,19z/data=!3m1!5s0x43d378bb50c5fead:0x6ad9c3d5313685d0!4m8!3m7!1s0x4876719d9607664f:0xe0ff025c43d02388!8m2!3d51.4731271!4d-0.4870388!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F11f3dc1f39?entry=ttu) mention overcrowding and queues – I don't want to risk being unable to find a seat or being turned away and being late for the calls. Club Aspire doesn't have seats with the same privacy and, from their [reviews](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Club+Aspire+Lounge/@51.4700657,-0.4868253,17z/data=!4m8!3m7!1s0x48767175fe82d11f:0x414e4b2677854890!8m2!3d51.4700657!4d-0.4868253!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F11c44ffrk_?entry=ttu), comes with a similar risk of overcrowding; however it might be quieter and less busy than Plaza Premium and offers [pre-booking](https://no1lounges.com/priority-pass-pre-book/) for members of selected lounge access programs to guarantee access. The other option is to find somewhere else in the terminal like a restaurant, café or even a part of the terminal that has less traffic.

So with those options, I'm looking for recommendations. The priority is somewhere quiet enough for a call and has good WiFi (at a minimum good enough for a voice call, ideally good enough for a video call). Are the risks of the two lounges overblown? Or do you know somewhere else in the terminal that's good for taking calls?

<sub>If the specificity helps for a better answer: I'll be at the terminal on a Wednesday afternoon. However, I'm open to more general answers.</sub>

Comment: https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/airport-services/meeting-rooms says there are Regus Express meeting rooms, but they don't show up on the Regus website, and a number of other sites say they are either temporarily closed or unavailable. Maybe try to call them to know for sure?

Comment: @jcaron: thanks for suggesting. Unfortunately, it looks like they're landside which combined with my schedule would make it difficult to get to my flight on time. Your comment will help others who come across this question, though.

Comment: There is also [No1 Lounges](https://no1lounges.com/faqs/) which says *"If you're transferring through Heathrow and would like to use the lounge, follow the signs for flight connections when you land. If you don't land in T3 or T5 you'll need to get the free airport terminal transfer bus and follow the signs the terminals. Transferring between terminals can take up to 90 minutes, so we would recommend only using our lounge if you are departing from Terminal 3 or Terminal 5."*

Comment: @WeatherVane: No1 lounges is the operator for the Club Aspire lounge mentioned in the post.